# Android sqlite error for login activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

When the user logs in, the application seems to crash and then work. An error appears on the LogCat saying:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: cliff (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, name, password FROM Users WHERE name=cliff
```

Why would it throw up an error but then work? Can anyone see my problem. Below is my code...

```
 public class DBAdapter {
static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
static final String KEY_USERNAME = "name";
static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
static final String KEY_CARDNUM = "cardnum";
static final String KEY_CARDNAME = "cardname";
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CPDB";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Users";
static final String DATABASE_TABLEC = "Cards";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table Users (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "name text not null, password text not null, cardnum integer not null, cardname text not null);";


final Context context;

DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter (Context ctx){
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        try{
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version" + oldVersion + "to" + newVersion + "which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users");
        onCreate (db);

    }
}

//--opens the DB--
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db= DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//--close the DB--
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
 } 

//--retrieves chosen user--
  public Cursor checkUser(String username) throws SQLException{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,       KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD}, KEY_USERNAME + "=" + username, null, null, null, null,null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

}
```

And then for the login java class ............

```
 public class login extends Activity {
Button btn1,btn2;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* Called when the activity is first created*/
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bttn_signup);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bttn_signin);
}

 public void onClick(View view){

    if(view.getId() == R.id.bttn_signup) {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.cardpocket.cardpocket.signup"));
    }

    if(view.getId() == R.id.bttn_signin) {

     EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_email);
        EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);

        String username = email.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();


        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.checkUser(username);
        //set someUsers as a list
        ArrayList<String> theUser = new ArrayList<>();


        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String aUser = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("password"));
                theUser.add(aUser);


            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

      if (theUser.contains(password)) {

          startActivity(new Intent("com.cardpocket.cardpocket.mainactivity"));

          /*
       //set the value and pass to the mainactivity
          Intent i = new Intent(this, mainactivity.class);
          i.putExtra("username", username);
          startActivity(i);}*/

      } else {
          //do something else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and forgotten to quote your values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT _id, name, password FROM Users WHERE name='cliff'
                                                          ^-----^---
```

without the quotes, `cliff` is treated as a field/table name, which doesn't exist. With the quotes, `'cliff'` is a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear : the column "cliff" does not exist...

You have to put quotes around *cliff* in your SQL request

```
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,       KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD}, KEY_USERNAME + "= '" + username + "'", null, null, null, null,null);
```

Also, I advise you to use prepared SQL queries, this way :

```
String selection = "KEY_USERNAME = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { username };
String[] columns = {KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD};
Cursor cursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, columns, selection, selectionArgs , null, null, null,null);
```

It will add quotes for you and ensure your request is safer.

Link : [Official documentation of query method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  cliff you have to use(quotes)'cliff'. Without quotes it will be identified as coloumn by sqlite and probably give a error no such coloumn (cliff).